# How to get the variable passed from another page when form is submitted

Tags: php

I'm working on password `reset` in core `php`.

I'm sending `code` variable from `reset.php` to `resetPassword.php` page like this:

`reset.php`

```
$code = uniqid(true);
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/resetPassword.php?code=$code"
```

`resetPassword.php`

```
global $code;
if(!isset($_GET['code'])){

    echo "There is No Code there !!!";
}

if(isset($_GET['code'])){
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    echo "The code is set at first , just at visit of the page ".$code;
}

// make sure there is row in the table that matches that passed code 
$findEmail = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT `email` from resetpasswords WHERE `code` = '$code' ");


if(mysqli_num_rows($findEmail)==0){    // if no row found

    echo "<h2 class = 'text text-center'>No Record regarding this email !</h2>";
    exit();
}



  // when form submits

    if(isset($_POST['reset'])){

    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $confirm  = md5($_POST['confirm']);
    if($password!=$confirm){
        echo "Password Don't matches !";
        exit();
    }
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($findEmail);
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $updatePass = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE `user` SET user_password = '$confirm' where email = '$email'");
    if($updatePass){
        $query = mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM resetpasswords where code = '$code' ");
        exit('Password Updated, Please Login with the New Password');
    }
    else{
        exit('Something went wrong');
    }


}
```

On the same page `resetPassword.php`, I have the following code:

```
  <form action="resetPassword.php" method="POST">
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password2" onkeyup="checkPass();">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="confirm2">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm" id="confirm2" onkeyup="checkPass();">
                    <span id="confirm-message2" class="confirm-message"></span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $code;?>">   
                <input type="submit" name="reset" value="Update Password" class="btn btn-success">  
        </form>
```

**Problem:**

The problem is when I submit the form , it goes all the way to the top of the page, and start executing the `resetPassword.php` page from the top, due to which for `resetPassowrd.php` page, it can't `get` that `$code` variable.

Because when I submit the form,the condition `(!isset($_GET['code']))` at top of `resetPassword.php` becomes true and it gives me:
 `There is No Code there !!!`

And I want to have that `$code` when I submit the form.

**What I tried:**

I tried to use `hidden` field with value of `$code` but that didn't worked.

please help me thanks

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: **Warning!** Don't use md5 for password hashing! [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) even states: _"Warning - It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm"_. You should use PHP's [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to create a secure hash. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, I'll definitely use it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the below points

1) Use prepared statements and parameterized queries.

2) Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` to secure your password.

3) In `resetPassword.php` page, if you submit the form with `action="resetPassword.php"` this will redirect to resetPassword.php. So replace your action with this

```
$full_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

<form action="<?php echo $full_url ?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: it gives me `Undefined index: email `

Comment: What exactly is this suppose to do and solve? If you want the form to post to the same page, just remove the `action` attribute all together and it's done. However, I'm not sure how that would solve passing the code though?

Comment: In your form there are only two fields one is password and one more is confirm. So how can you access this  $_POST['email'] ?

Comment: If your $code variable is unique, use $email = $row['email']; instead of  $email = $_POST['email'];  this may work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing name attribute in your hidden field and hence you are not able to find the value of $code.

Instead of

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $code;?>">
```

Try

```
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $code;?>" name="code" />
```